# Qml cannot load qtquickdialogsplugin.dll library when using Pyside6

Tags: qml, pyside6

Qml shows an error in terminal when I try to show a qml window with QtQuick.Dialogs module import:

```
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3
```

```
qml: Error:file:///D:/LEET/QtDesignProjects/LEET/DDTXMLViewScreen.qml:5 Cannot load library C:\\Users\\Alexa\\PycharmProjects\\LEET\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PySide6\\qml\\QtQuick\\Dialogs\\qtquickdialogsplugin.dll
```

Of course file "qtquickdialogsplugin.dll" exists in the specified directory. All others imports work good.

I can't use QtQuick.Dialogs with pyside6?

Tried to uninstall and reinstall pyside6 again, didn't help, now pyside6 version 6.4.2 is installed. I use PyCharm and QT design studio.

Tried to change import statement to:

```
import QtQuick.Dialogs
```

but with same result

With pyside2 this line works just great, but I don't want to use pyside2 for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Because no one answered, I'll take the liberty of answering myself - I missed the fact that the QML is contained not only in the PySide, but also in the PyQt. Given the cosmetic difference between the libraries for my application, I just changed one to the other and everything works fine under PyQt6 now.
Keeping in mind the number of strange problems I've faced, I can't recommend anyone to use the PySide library. All these  oddities disappeared after switching to PyQt library and now everything works or doesn't work as expected.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).